# What is a good work-around for co-authoring issues with vba macros on excel

Tags: excel, vba, autosave

I have designed a macro enabled workbook that is saved on OneDrive that shows a daily roster and task list for employees at our company. The workbook can add tasks or mark them as completed on the multiple computers it can be opened on. As I discovered soon after making this workbook, the co-authoring feature is not compatible with macro enabled workbooks, so if the file is opened on multiple computers the error message comes up saying that changes cannot be saved because of unsupported feature changes made by someone else. The employees get confused and annoyed with it and end up saving multiple copies of the file with each individual change they make which is fairly inconvenient.

I learnt that simply turning off autosave and therefore the co-authoring feature when opening it up will prevent issues, however, if the file is opened with autosave turned off, it is unable to be opened by any other users. It is not entirely necessary that the file needs to be open on multiple computers at once, but it would be nice if there is a solution for that. What is necessary though is the ability to be able to switch who has the file open, so that if someone leaves it open on a computer and someone else wants to open it on their computer, it will open and then on the previous users computer it would turn autosave off, or close the file or just send a notification to prevent errors popping up on the other users computer.

Below is some of the code blocks where I attempt to take advantage of co-authoring and use a cell change to detect when another computer opens up the file and use that event to turn off autosave to prevent the error messages showing up. As you can guess this runs into the problem that the code itself that changes the cell triggers the error message "Unsupported feature changes made by someone else" before it can prevent it.

```
Module 1: Public TOmsgShown As Boolean

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    TOmsgShown = False
    Dim currentuser As Range
    Set currentuser = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 100)
    If IsEmpty(currentuser) = False Then
        userswitch = MsgBox(currentuser.Value & " has currently got this workbook open, and it is only able to be edited by one person at a time. " & _
        "Do you want to take over editing capabilities? No to open this as read-only (any changes made will not be saved) or Yes to force " & currentuser.Value & " to switch to read-only.", vbYesNo)
        If userswitch = vbNo Then
            ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess (xlReadOnly)
            ThisWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False
        Else
            currentuser.Value = Application.UserName
        End If
    Else
        currentuser.Value = Application.UserName
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
     If Sheets(1).Cells(1, 100).Value <> Application.UserName And TOmsgShown = False Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False
        ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess (xlReadOnly)
        TOmsgShown = True
        MsgBox (Sheets(1).Cells(1, 100).Value & " has opened up this roster and taken over editing capabilities. You will now be switched to Read-Only mode and can not save any changes made. Re-open this workbook to continue editing.")
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Are there any vba events that can be used that won't trigger the error to make this method work, or otherwise, is there a way I can use code to deal with the error message directly so that it won't show and prompt employees to save a copy file unnecessarily?

Comment: I Would have 1 workbook for each employee that feeds from a master workbook. Once they end their job, push a button which will save their changes into the master workbook in a matter of seconds so problems by 2 users trying to save at the same time would be rare...

Comment: If you are getting "unsupported feature" messages, It's not because it's "macro enabled". It's because it's got unsupported features. Fix that, and the problem will go away.

Comment: I have spent days trying to google for this error but have not found much, what would be some examples of unsupported features? it seems any macro that I run no matter how simple is a "unsupported feature" as it will bring up that error

Comment: Also thanks for the idea Damian, in the end i did it in a way that everyone who opens the file it will open as a new copy, record all the keystrokes and changes they make onto a seperate document that keeps record of the differences in everyones copies, and then is able to put those changes back into the main document in a way to avoid conflicts and overwriting data. It was a little bit convoluted to code but it works well, so it turns out to be a good solution.